# Elasticsearch query not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I am using an existing infrastructure, I am trying to understand what is wrong with my query because I receive no results.

I have the following model -

```
X = {
    "id" : "string",
    "name" : "string",
    "hidden" : boolean,
    "description" : "string",
    "status" : "string",
    "type" : "string"
}
```

I am trying to create a condition that will exclude results - under "must_not" I have created a bool query that has a "must" that contains 3 terms.

Pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve -

IF X.id IN [] AND x.hidden == true AND x.status == "FINISHED" THEN don't score -- only if the entire condition is met.

Even though I have data that should be returning, I am receiving nothing. Any assist will be great. Thanks.

Query -

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query" : "{phrase}",
          "fields" : [
            "searchData.body*^1.0",
            "searchData.description*^3.0",
            "searchData.name*^4.0",
            "searchData.taskBody*^1.0",
            "searchData.topics^2.0"
          ],
          "type" : "best_fields",
          "operator" : "OR",
          "slop" : 0,
          "prefix_length" : 0,
          "max_expansions" : 50,
          "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "context.X.id" : [
            "04cb64b5-bf28-4e04-a7f1-6f93a8caa10c",
            "368bf798-5ec7-4f73-904e-ec22818c4f6b",
            "8ccb61ab-364a-4303-b21f-e930bb8b8071",
            "7675e70a-1216-49d5-915c-a3c3f919a1bf",
            "c9d976d8-bbe3-44db-9d97-5fafc4af0d3f",
            "234f9f61-69fe-41e8-89e8-a5c2c4e99e0a",
            "c0a813e6-4e32-4993-a53f-bb16b16ef976",
            "261da1c2-edc5-4f51-807e-603fe9d9712a",
            "dc2d1e94-6653-420c-96ce-bccdd7e187f1",
            "zzzzzzzz-xxxx-4e04-a7f1-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
            "xxxxxxxx-bf28-yyyy-a7f1-kkkkkkkkkkkk",
            "yyyyyyyy-bf28-4e04-a7f1-mmmmmmmmmmmm",
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "must_not" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "term" : {
                "context.X.id" : {
                  "value" : [
                    "04cb64b5-bf28-4e04-a7f1-6f93a8caa10c",
                    "368bf798-5ec7-4f73-904e-ec22818c4f6b",
                    "8ccb61ab-364a-4303-b21f-e930bb8b8071",
                    "7675e70a-1216-49d5-915c-a3c3f919a1bf",
                    "c9d976d8-bbe3-44db-9d97-5fafc4af0d3f",
                    "234f9f61-69fe-41e8-89e8-a5c2c4e99e0a",
                    "c0a813e6-4e32-4993-a53f-bb16b16ef976",
                    "261da1c2-edc5-4f51-807e-603fe9d9712a",
                    "dc2d1e94-6653-420c-96ce-bccdd7e187f1"
                  ],
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "context.X.status" : {
                  "value" : "FINISHED",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "context.X.hidden" : {
                  "value" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

Mapping:

```
"X": {
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "id_normalizer"
                  },
                  "description": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
----------------------------------before edit
                  "hidden": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
----------------------------------
----------------------------------after edit
                  "hidden": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
----------------------------------
                  "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "status": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

Comment: It usually helps to run a kind of binary search: temporary remove parts of the query until the result changes then dig into the last removed part in the same manner. Also could you please share your ES mapping? If your fields aren't `keyword`s the `term` queries might return not what you expect.

Comment: @ilvar thanks for the reply, I have added the mapping and indeed I am missing a ```keyword``` definition. I will update now and try again

Comment: @ilvar unfortunately it did not help. Still receiving results that satisfy the must_not conditions. I have edited the original post with the change I have made. I'm just wondering if my query is ok, meaning if I set 3 "must" terms inside a list of must_not, should it do the obvious and not return any documents that meet these 3 conditions?

Comment: Your `bool`s setup would exclude docs that match *all three* `must` clauses. I would try to run those queries one by one and confirm that they return what you expect. You might need to replace `term` with `match` queries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ilvar who got my attention to the `keyword` definition, I have noticed that the `status` field is defined as `text`.

This field is getting it's values from a `Status` enum and the string representation of that enum is being saved.

For some reason results hasn't returned until I searched for the `X.status.keyword` path ( [ES documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) mention that a field who's type `keyword` is not explicit so it can be several types)